# no sound, mic, cameras after installing ChromeOS on rubbish windows laptop-tablet

Tags: linux, audio, drivers, microphone, google-chrome-os

I thought it would be worth the risk of completely wiping my windows laptop-tablet (iOTA One, model: 2120) that was ultra slow and practically unusable and installing chromeOS on it (actually cloud-ready by Neverware but practically the same thing). And WOW! It's amazingly fast now. But... I've lost all sound, mic, cameras, touch and brightness control (touch and brightness don't really bother me but it would be nice if they worked too) :(

The brightness actually did work when i installed ubuntu on it [(I also posted a question then here)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301286) and I got different outputs that may or may not help.

I installed linux in chromeOS to get some outputs

Output of `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma]
00:01.0 Unassigned class [ffff]: Red Hat, Inc Virtio console
00:02.0 Unassigned class [ffff]: Red Hat, Inc Virtio block device
00:03.0 Unassigned class [ffff]: Red Hat, Inc Virtio block device
00:04.0 Unassigned class [ffff]: Red Hat, Inc Device 105b
00:05.0 Unassigned class [ffff]: Red Hat, Inc Virtio RNG
00:06.0 Unassigned class [ffff]: Red Hat, Inc Virtio memory balloon
00:07.0 Unassigned class [ffff]: Red Hat, Inc Virtio network device
00:08.0 Unassigned class [ffff]: Red Hat, Inc Device 107f
00:09.0 Unassigned class [ffff]: Red Hat, Inc Device 1053
00:0a.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller
00:0b.0 USB controller: Fresco Logic FL1000G USB 3.0 Host Controller
```

Output of `inxi -SMA`

```
System:    Host: penguin Kernel: 5.4.48-06434-gd868196d13af x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: N/A Distro: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) 
Machine:   Type: N/A System: ChromiumOS product: crosvm v: N/A serial: <root required> 
           Mobo: N/A model: N/A serial: N/A BIOS: crosvm v: N/A date: N/A 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel 82801AA AC97 Audio driver: snd_intel8x0 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.48-06434-gd868196d13af
```

Please say if you want me to show any other ouputs

Comment: Any one in particular? I've tried ubuntu (see link in question)

Comment: @JakesMS, Sorry, I missed that you had tried to install Ubuntu. My search showed that others had similar issues; though Ubuntu gave access to brightness, camera, sound, etc. were still unusable. At least you should be able to reinstall Windows with their drivers, at https://drp.su/en/laptops/iota/iota?os=windows-10-x64 . Aorry I was of no help.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome OS as Linux: and there's one particular kind of tablet that for some reason has limited(very) linux support. Cherry trail.

I have 2 such devices, and linux hates it.

You need a specific kernel to get it to even display.

Networking, sound and the touch interfaces are what I have issues with.

The latest kernel makes it Kinda Usable... but still lacking in the networking.

as to fixing it... im sorry i dont know.